# How to run same set of python scripts parallelly at different folders?

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing

I want to run some python scripts in parallel across different input directories(eg:0,1,2,3,4) but before running the scripts I need to change the working directories to each folders. I am using Linux Platform and I tried os.chdir() to change the directory dynamically but it will only take the first directory and ends the process

```
import os
import time
from multiprocessing import Pool


def par(input_dir):
    os.chdir("/home/user/xyz/%s" %input_dir)
    print(f"start process:{input_dir}")
    os.system("python /home/user/xyz/model/Preprocessing_directory/Driver.py metadata.json")
    os.system("python /home/vishnuk/xyz/model/model_directory/Driver.py metadata.json ")
    print(f"end process:{input_dir}")


if _name_ == "_main_":
    starttime = time.time()
    pool = Pool()
    pool.map(par, range(0, 5))
    pool.close()
    endtime = time.time()
    print(f"Time taken {endtime-starttime} seconds")
```

I want to change the working directory to "/home/user/xyz/0", /home/user/xyz/1 .. etc and run the rest of the scripts parallelly across different CPUs. Any idea on how to get this done parallelly in python will be very helpful as I am very much new to python

Comment: 1. You are missing an `import os`. 2. It should be `if __name__ == '__main__':`. 3. You need a comma between `par` and `range(0, 5)`. I can't see why all your calls to `os.chdir` are not working as expected. Are you sure the directories exist? Try catching and printing any exceptions raised by the call to `chdir`. Or follow call to `chdir` with a call to `os.getcwd()` and print result.

Comment: Thank ypu for pointing it. Actually it got worked, thing is about range operation as it works secondlast digit (here 0,1,2,3,4) and 5 will not come. I did range (0,1) as test case and it stopped after first process (i.e. 0). My mistake. But Thanks for going through the code